# Make all flex box children take the height of the highest child

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is my flex box UL:

```
ul {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    max-width: 1159px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap:25px;
}
```

And the `li`'s:

```
ul>li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    flex-basis: calc((100% - 50px) * 0.333333);
    border-radius: 35px;
    position:relative;
}
```

I have some rows, each row containing 3 `li`'s, and on each row, all the `li`'s have the height of the highest `li` on the row, depending on how large is its content. The problem is that this height isn't kept on the second/third/etc row - all `li`'s on the second row, for example, will have the height of the highest `li` on the second row, but there's nothing to ensure this coincides with the max height of the first row. I would like to make all the `li`'s, regardless of their content and of the row they are on, have the height of the highest `li` in the entire list, however large it may be. I would like to accomplish this with css only and by using flexbox (not css grid). Is this possible?

I tried `height:auto` or `align-self:stretch` or `align-`content:stretch`, nothing seems to work. However, I would like to be sure.

Comment: It is not possible with css or flex box directly. As the text will increase, the div height will increase definitely. But if you want fixed height, you can check height of the max element and update the other li height based on that using javascript. If you want I can give you example in the answer

Comment: This could be done using grid and grid-auto-rows for this. It can't be done in flex.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it with flexbox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.col-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
<h2>Equal Height Columns with Flexbox</h2>
<p>Make the columns match the height of the tallest column.</p>    
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col" style="background:orange">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>    
  <div class="col" style="background:yellow">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>    
  <div class="col" style="background:orange">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
  </div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

From: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp (last option; the flex-wrap is my addition).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't do it with flex, but it's possible with grid:

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
```

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elegant-wescoff-nhryks